# Add QObject to QT main loop in order to recieve dbus messages

Tags: c++, qt, ipc, dbus, qdbus

I have a Qt console application. In this application, there is an object of type "my_client". "my_client" objects have an slot named "messageSlot". This slot is connected to a DBUS message.

So the main function of this qt app is as follows :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    if (!QDBusConnection::sessionBus().isConnected())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus.\n"
                "To start it, run:\n"
                "\teval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax`\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!QDBusConnection::sessionBus().registerService("org.brlapi.server"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",
                qPrintable(QDBusConnection::sessionBus().lastError().message()));
        std::cout << qPrintable(QDBusConnection::sessionBus().lastError().message())
                  << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    my_client client;
    new myClassAdaptor(&client);
    QDBusConnection::sessionBus().registerObject("/", &client);

    QDBusConnection::sessionBus().connect("org.my.server",
                                          "/",
                                          "org.my.server",
                                          "message",
                                          &client,
                                          SLOT(my_client::messageSlot(QString, QString)));   

    return a.exec();
}
```

And my_client is as follows :

```
class my_client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    my_client()
    {

    }

private slots:
    void messageSlot(QString msg1, QString msg2)
    {
        std::cout << "CLIENT : I've received a message : " << msg1.toStdString()
                  << "," << msg2.toStdString() << std::endl;
        QDBusMessage msg = QDBusMessage::createSignal("/", "org.my.server", "message");
        msg << "Hello!!!" << "Are you ok?";
        QDBusConnection::sessionBus().send(msg);
    }
};
```

But with this code I can't receive DBUS message. I think that the problem is that client object hasn't a main loop and therefore can't receive signals.

Am I right? If so, how can we add client object to main loop? and if not, what is the problem with this code? how can I receive dbus messages and handle them with QT signal/slot?

Comment: The syntax for your slot is wrong in your `connect` call. It should be `SLOT(messageSlot(QString, QString))`.

Comment: @thuga My bad!!! Thanks, that was the problem.